Parallelize one topic messages over multiple JMS connections?
Say I have JMS topic A and a single JMS connection to the broker C.
A has many messages that are extremely large and so when they are sent over a single connection, C, it frequently backs up and the consumers attached to C cannot keep up (bottleneck is the single connection).
Is there a way that I can have multiple connections receive messages on topic A in parallel while maintaining ordering?
The key is that I need to process all messages in order on A but I would like to split up the TCP receiving work.

This post (stackoverflow.com) and its answers may be related. I do not think that what you want is possible with JMS.

Does it take a long time process the message(s) (i.e. not just download them)?

When you say, "consumers attached to C cannot keep up," do you mean that since the single connection is a bottleneck that consumers attached to C are rather starving?

It is possible to have consumers on multiple different connections receiving messages from the same JMS topic subscription, but it requires the shared topic subscription functionality introduced in JMS 2. Does your broker support (at least) JMS 2?

Personally, I would look to avoid having very large messages in a queue, and instead use some kind of shared large object storage system (S3 or equivalent) for the bulky data, with messages in the queue that point to their location.

It is possible to have consumers on multiple different connections receiving messages from the same JMS topic subscription, but it requires the shared topic subscription functionality introduced in JMS 2.
That said, it will be up to your application to maintain order at that point.
